# How to change usb file system?

Tags: usb, filesystems, formatting, usb-flash-drive

How to change the traditional file system of a usb flashdrive(fat32) into ntfs or other file system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This article](http://www.ntfs.com/quest22.htm) answers your question:

Q: How do I format a USB Flash Drive to NTFS file system?
A: To enable NTFS on your USB Flash Drive drive (USB Flash Memory):

1. Right click My Computer and select Manage.
2. Open the Device Manager and find your USB drive under the Disk Drives heading.

   [image]
3. Right click the drive and select Properties.
4. Choose Policies tab and select the "Optimize for performance" option.

   [image]
5. Click OK.
6. Open My Computer.
7. Select Format on the flash drive.

   [image]
8. Choose NTFS in the File System dropdown box.
9. Device Formatting is completed.

   [image]

**Important**: To remove a device safely without data loss use a "safely remove hardware" procedure or Eject function from Windows Explorer.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could [use convert.exe](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314097):

> `> CONVERT` *driveletter*: `/FS:NTFS`

where *driveletter* is the driveletter of your flash drive of course.

Comment: One advantage of this method is that you don't need to format the drive. The data can stay on it.

Comment: Also supposing you are on windows btw.

Comment: in particular, it's a win-XP utility.  any confirmation it also exists on vista & win-7?

Comment: @~quack: Just checked, en I can confirm that the tool is still included in Windows 7.

Comment: thanks!  i just noticed your MS link didn't specify them, so it was worth asking.  :)